# I can't start my ubuntu with the image below

Tags: boot, startup

I was warned that the room of my disk was nearly empty yesterday, but I didn't clean enough room for it. I don't know if that's the problem? Hope anyone can help me with it.
When I open my Ubuntu, it just appeared:
[image: img]

Comment: Can you try the command `exit` and see if it boots afterwards? Also, did you set up any custom mount points to some locally shared directories?

Comment: Also, did you set up automount for the `/mnt/hgfs` drive which is now absent?